# Recovering data from a hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

After some fiasco with installing Windows 8 Developer Preview, I ended up with my 1.5TB HDD wiped. Unfortunately, I had some data on there that I needed.

So I started up Recuva and recovered most all the data that I needed. I think it's anywhere from 130 GB to 250 GB. However, I don't have another HDD to back the data up to - except for a SSD with 16.7 GB free and my laptop's 320GB HDD.

I'd like to recover all of this data. What should I do? Should I make a new partition and copy everything there? Is there a FREE cloud service that I can get to synchronize all my data from my C: drive while Recuva is copying it there, as I have 16.7GB free there? Could I connect my laptop to my desktop and have Recuva recover it to my laptop's HDD?

Comment: Mounting a folder from you laptop to your desktop over a network is simple, but you'll have to tell us which OSs and if you have a network available.

Comment: Go buy a backup drive before life decides you need another lesson in why you should back things up.

Comment: You need to go out and purchase additional storage.  Modifying the partition WILL make it where you lose some data. That is a gurantee it might be the single file you must have.  While you can use the SSD drive it might be easier to just purchase a 500GB USB for the $100 if its that important to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to not go with some wireless-transfer method.

Instead, I used a spare SATA cable to connect my laptop's HDD to the desktop. It worked near-flawlessly; however, it might have something to do with [My PC's Windows 8 partition got destroyed. How can I fix it?](https://superuser.com/questions/406871/my-pcs-windows-8-partition-got-destroyed-how-can-i-fix-it).

As soon as I booted into Windows 8, I transfered the data and got most of it back.

Answer (score 0):

You still want to use this machine and its HD, but just not write over those files that still on a partition there, right?
So use a partitioning tool to reduce that existing partition that spans  the enter disk, to a smaller partition that just contains those files (250GB). GParted is a great tool that  can be  booted off a CD or USB. [Here's the GParted download page.](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php)
Then create a partition using the rest of the drive (labeled with a name unique so you will recognize it) and then reload a new OS of your choice there.
You can keep those files backed up there, or merge them in the new partition.
Moving them to a cloud service will take a very long time, and obviously 16.7 GB is much smaller than 250gb.
Another alternative, is to boot a live Unix CD (like Ubuntu or Mint). That will give you access to that partition and also network access to your laptop's shared folders, where you could copy the files to.